# Liferay @ResourceURL caching parameters on ajax call

Tags: ajax, json, liferay, jackson, portlet

This is my current situation and problem. I have 2 dropdowns, when I change selection in first, second populates with data depending what I have chosen (for that it uses ajax of course).
When I submit data to the `@Controller`, it returns me to the same page, and when I try to do the same action again (choose select option in first dropdown to get valid information in second) no matter what I select I get information from previous request (old one before I was returned to that page). That is: Controller gets wrong information (old one from previous page) that for it it populates second dropdown with that old request info.

Like my ajax call has some caching turned on and uses old info. This is how it looks like in my code

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="getURL" id="dataurl" escapeXml="false"></portlet:resourceURL>
```

The scripts:

```
<script>
var type = $("#pi_selectType option:selected").val();

$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    url : "${getURL}",
    data : {
        info1: "${PO.data1}",
        info2 : type
    },
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
    ....
});
<script>
```

I have tried to add parameter in ajax call:

```
cache: false
```

but problem remains.

Is there a way to reset Portlet url after `ResourceMapping` Request, or something like that, because I think that might solve this problem. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Which version of liferay are you using 6.0 or 6.1? CE or EE? Also you may want to look at Liferay issue [LPS-3022](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-3022), as per this issue what is happening is that instead of creating a new `resourceURL` with fresh parameters, it adds the new parameters to the old `resourceURL`, due to which it serves the same data. To find out if this is the case with you, install Firebug in firefox and check the AJAX request and the URL generated in the Firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

Use current timestamp as third parameter. I have encountered such problem in the the past and this is how I solved that.

```
    data : {
       info1: "${PO.data1}",
       info2 : type,
       info3 : <current timestamp long>
    },
```

By appending current timestamp as a parameter to the request, it is always treated as a new request.